# I'm using javascript on visual studio code and am attempting to console.log into a live server, it isn't working for me

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, console.log, liveserver

I'm creating a countdown project as a beginner, here is my code:

```js
const newYears = '1 Jan 2021';

function countdown() {
    const newYearsDate = new Date(newYears);
    const currentDate = new Date();

    const seconds = (newYearsDate - currentDate) / 1000;

    console.log(newYearsDate - currentDate);
}

// initial call
countdown();
setInterval(countdown, 1000);
```

Above is the console.log that isn't appearing in my live server console.

Here is my html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Countdown Timer</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
      <script scr="script.js" defer></script>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>New Years Eve</h1>
      <div class="countdown-container">
         <div class="countdown-el days-c">
            <p class="big-text" id="days">0</p>
            <span>days</span>
         </div>
         <div class="countdown-el hours-c">
            <p class="big-text" id="hours">0</p>
            <span>hours</span>
         </div>
         <div class="countdown-el minutes-c">
            <p class="big-text" id="minutes">0</p>
            <span>minutes</span>
         </div>
         <div class="countdown-el seconds-c">
            <p class="big-text" id="seconds">0</p>
            <span>seconds</span>
         </div>
      </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

I'm sure there is a simple solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have spelled source wrong in the script tag.

Here is what you have written:

```
<script scr="script.js" defer></script>
```

where as it should be written as

```
<script src="script.js" defer></script>
```

as you can see you have spelled the source attribute wrong. so the script is not imported and it does not run.

Comment: Your welcome. please mark the answer as the solution